# How to search for value not in an SQL querying a XML column in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    [content_id] AS [LinkID]
    , dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('root/Physicians/name'))) AS [Physician Name]
    , [content_status] AS [Status]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).value('(root/Physicians/picture/img/@src)[1]','varchar(255)') AS [Image]
    , dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('root/Physicians/gender'))) AS [Gender]
    , CAST ([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/OfficeLocations/office1/a') AS [Office1]
    , dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST ([content_html] as XML).query('/root/Physicians/langF3'))) AS [Lang3]
    , dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST ([content_html] as XML).query('/root/Physicians/langF4'))) AS [Lang4]
    , dbo.usp_ClearHTMLTags(CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST ([content_html] as XML).query('/root/Physicians/langF5'))) AS [Lang5]
FROM
    [mydb].[dbo].[content]
WHERE
    (content_html LIKE '%'+@strInsurance+'%')
```

`strInsurance` is the DropDownList value that are being searched by the user. At the current state the query searches for any occurences and displays it in the result.

I have set up a form where there is two options, either check mark the `All Insurances` or enter what insurances the physician doesn't accept.

A screenshot of the form:

[image]

Sample XML from column `content_html`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Physicians>
        <name>Z H MD</name>
        <picture />
        <gender>M</gender>
        <langAccept />
        <insAll>false</insAll>
        <notIns1>
            <a href="/default.aspx?id=2871" title="Great West Healthcare">Great West Healthcare</a>
        </notIns1>
        <notIns2>
            <a href="/default.aspx?id=2862" title="Archcare Advantage SNP">Archcare Advantage SNP</a>
        </notIns2>
        <notIns3>
            <a href="/default.aspx?id=2877" title="Magnacare">Magnacare</a>
        </notIns3>
        <notIns4 />
        <notIns5 />
        <notIns6 />
        <notIns7 />
        <notIns8 />
        <notIns9 />
        <notIns10 />
        <specialty />
        <specialty2 />
        <specialty3 />
    </Physicians>
</root>
```

So, the above physician will accept all insurances except the three mentioned above.

What I would like to achieve: If the user selects `Great West Healthcare` {from the dropdownlist}, the above physician won't show up but if the user selects 'Blue Cross Blue Shield` {from the dropdownlist} the above physician will show up.

How can I modify the SQL query to achieve that or using code behind.

I currently have a repeater which just displays each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is my first time using SQLFiddle to provide a link.  I tested this out and it worked for me.  I apologize if it fails for some reason.

It looks like your HTML column is a varchar column.  If you change it into an XML column you can use the XML query functions.  Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/254b2/3).

Additionally, if possible you should restructure your XML to remove the "notIns1"..."notIns10" elements and replace them with a set of "notIns" elements.  (similar to good normalization rules.)

Comment: The data type is nvarchar. I will definitely try and let you know :) Thanks. So you recommend have multiple of the notins then have notins#?

Comment: And the value can be anything, the three entries are just an example.

Comment: Yes, having NotIns1 through 10 provides an artificial limit on, in this case, the number of different insurance types that are not accepted.  (it seems to me that this could easily be more than 10 items, but I'm not a subject matter expert.) Well-formatted XML usually has a group element that contains members of the group.  Ex:  <Books><Book Title="Book1" /><Book Title="Book2" /></Books>   It also make writing code to process the XML more difficult, since you need to look for 10 different tag names instead of just one.